# Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called in 'NgModule'

Tags: angular

Всем привет!!!

```
ERROR in ../ngx-resizer/ngx-resizer.ts(13,2): Error during template compile of 'NgxResizeModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called in 'NgModule'
    'NgModule' calls 'ɵmakeDecorator'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.
node_modules/ngx-resizer/node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить данный конфликт?)

Comment: ERROR in ../ngx-resizer/ngx-resizer.ts(13,2): Error during template compile of 'NgxResizeModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called in 'NgModule'
    'NgModule' calls 'ɵmakeDecorator'.

Решилось изменив ng build --prod && ng run ng-universal-demo:server:production на ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false && ng run ng-universal-demo:server:production

Comment: Остался вопрос с ERROR in node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.
node_modules/ngx-resizer/node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.

Comment: вы приводите ошибки, но не приводите код, обожаю гадание на гуще

Comment: Я не знаю какой фрагмент Вам предоставить, потому как не понимаю где именно ошибка) Я так понимаю что конфликт изза разных версий библиотек которые юзают приложение и расширение(

Answer (score 0):

Как временное решение можно указать вот это строку в package.json

```
rm -r -f node_modules/ngx-resizer/node_modules
```

но это костыль(((